# R Notebook doesn't show the output in the preview and in the .nb.html file

Tags: html, r, rstudio, rnotebook

In Rstudio, I open a R Notebook, I run all chunks (I use the default script of Notebook). The "plot(cars)" display inline the plot. I save the Notebook (doc.Rmd). When I click on Preview, no output is shown in the preview. And no output is shown in the doc.nb.html.

How show the output in the preview and in the .nb.html file?

Comment: Add more details about your R notebook (Rstudio?) and reproducible code.